# Generate charts, graphs in PDF using iTextSharp in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, charts, itext, pdf-generation

I need to generate a PDF document at the server side of a ASP.NET Core 3.1. I am using iTextSharp to generate PDF. I am able to create data tables in PDF using iTextSharp. However I am not able to find a solution to add charts or graphs into the PDF using the same library.

I have used ChartJS and other similar packages but none of them let me create a chart at the backend and create it as an image to be embedded in the PDF.

Comment: you may need to create chart control in ASP.NET Core and then export in PDF. refer - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/export-chart-to-pdf-using-itextsharp/

Comment: There are web-services like https://image-charts.com that you can request to renders image of charts and then embed them inside PDF

Comment: Image charts looks like a monthly paid subscription service.

Comment: @SSD: There is no assembly provided in ASPNET core for system.web.datavisualization on which Chart control is based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 8/12/2020**

[image]

Create `excel` then convert to pdf. 
`Essential XlsIO` is a native .NET class librry that can be used to create and modify Microsoft Excel files.

[image]
XlsIO allows you to convert an entire workbook or a single worksheet into PDF document.

```
    [Route("/chart")]
    public IActionResult CreateChart()
    {
        using (ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine())
        {
            IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;
            application.DefaultVersion = ExcelVersion.Excel2013;
            IWorkbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Create(1);

            IWorksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

            //Inserts the sample data for the chart
            sheet.Range["A1"].Text = "Month";
            sheet.Range["B1"].Text = "Product A";
            sheet.Range["C1"].Text = "Product B";

            //Months
            sheet.Range["A2"].Text = "Jan";
            sheet.Range["A3"].Text = "Feb";
            sheet.Range["A4"].Text = "Mar";
            sheet.Range["A5"].Text = "Apr";
            sheet.Range["A6"].Text = "May";

            //Create a random Data
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i = 2; i <= 6; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 2; j <= 3; j++)
                {
                    sheet.Range[i, j].Number = r.Next(0, 500);
                }
            }
            IChartShape chart = sheet.Charts.Add();

            //Set chart type
            chart.ChartType = ExcelChartType.Line;

            //Set Chart Title
            chart.ChartTitle = "Product Sales comparison";

            //Set first serie
            IChartSerie productA = chart.Series.Add("ProductA");
            productA.Values = sheet.Range["B2:B6"];
            productA.CategoryLabels = sheet.Range["A2:A6"];

            //Set second serie
            IChartSerie productB = chart.Series.Add("ProductB");
            productB.Values = sheet.Range["C2:C6"];
            productB.CategoryLabels = sheet.Range["A2:A6"];

            //Saving the workbook as stream
            //FileStream stream = new FileStream("Chart.xlsx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            //workbook.SaveAs(stream);

            //Initialize XlsIO renderer.
            XlsIORenderer renderer = new XlsIORenderer();

            //Convert Excel document into PDF document 
            Syncfusion.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDocument = renderer.ConvertToPDF(sheet);

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            pdfDocument.Save(stream);

            stream.Flush(); //Always catches me out
            stream.Position = 0; //Not sure if this is required
            //stream.Dispose();

            return File(stream, "application/pdf", "chart.pdf");
        }

    }
```

---

> Generate PDF with Image by using **iTextsharp** in ASPNET Core 3.1

Here are the codes of `action`.

```
    [Route("/pdf")]
    public FileStreamResult GeneratePDFwithImage()
    {
        var imagepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "/images") + "/test.png";

        Document doc = new Document();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, stream);
        pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;

        doc.Open();
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
        Image png = Image.GetInstance(imagepath);
        doc.Add(png);
       
        doc.Close();

        stream.Flush(); //Always catches me out
        stream.Position = 0; //Not sure if this is required

        return File(stream, "application/pdf", "HelloWorld.pdf");

    }
```

> Test of result

[image]

Comment: In this case I don’t have a static image. I need to generate a bar graph from the dB and then write to a PDF.

Comment: What's the source date from DB? It's hard to find a chart-to-image generator using in asp.net core.

Comment: The user submits a set of form data that query’s dB and brings back results to be rendered in a pdf. I wish there was a straightforward way to render graphs in pdf.

Comment: I think Syncfusion is not a free version but a commercial license

Comment: Yes, that's  a trial version. Paying is better than nothing.

Comment: And I think the only way left is reinventing the wheel - draw a chart.